# Documentation example reputation is not displaying in the summary tab

Tags: bug, reputation, documentation-examples

The Documentation Example reputation is showing in the **[reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451726/arulkumar?tab=reputation)** tab and not in the **Reputation** section under the **[summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451726/arulkumar?tab=summary)** tab

Screenshots for reference:

**reputation tab:**

[image: reputation tab]

**summary tab:**

[image: summary tab]

Comment: Hmm. There's unfortunately no easy way to fix this. I agree that we should, but it's gonna take some thinking. The basic problem is that post votes and doc votes are stored in different places. We could do two queries to pull them all up, but that seems excessive. We could unify the data retrieval to go after the shared RepHistory table, but that has potentially non-trivial performance implications as well. I'll see what we can do, but it's gonna be a while.

Comment: @AdamLear : I can understand the complexity when the QA and Docs reputations are stored in the different tables and retrieve the data. I reported here for the tracking. I hope, as you mentioned it will fix little later without affect the performance.